# Angular recursive form creator with user selection

Tags: angular, .net-core, treeview

I am working on a project with Angular on the front-end and the .net-core on the backend. I try to explain my problem with an example;

```
                     How do you feel?
                      |            |
                     Good        Sick
                      /            \
           Do you have fever?     What is your problem?
           /         \                 |            \
         Yes         No              fever        stomache
         /            \                |                \
    Go Home          Go School      Go Home          Did you take pill?
                                                      /            \
                                                    Yes            No
                                                    /                \
                                                 Go Home           Go Doc.
```

This is a sort of a tree diagram which works due to the user's desicion. I can create this code behind and put in front of the user but how can I provide a system that allow the users create their own treeview?

In short, I need a suggestion about form generator due to the user's choice. And every answers should call the linked questions and go until the endpoint. Thanks.

Edit: Users can create their own treeview. Save. And they can open it in visual mode whenever they need. I mean by saying visual mode, user should use it. For the example above, the user gets up and starts with first question ow do I feel? hmm I feel sick. Tan the second question what is m problem? I have fever. etc.

Comment: you will need to implement something like https://balkan.app/OrgChartJS-Demos/DecisionTree